# How do I remove the sidebar toggle from a NavigationSplitView on iPad only in landscape mode

Tags: swiftui, ipad, ipados

How do I remove the sidebar toggle from a NavigationSplitView on iPad in landscape mode but keep it in portrait mode? Similar to how it works in the home app in iOS 17.

I have this so far but it doesn't work correctly at first launch before switching orientation once:

```swift
struct SidebarMainView: View {
    @Environment(\.horizontalSizeClass) private var horizontalSizeClass
    @State private var isPortrait = true

    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView {
            List {
                Text("1")
                Text("2")
                Text("3")
            }
            .listStyle(SidebarListStyle()).toolbar(removing: isPortrait ? .none : .sidebarToggle).navigationTitle("HP").onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIDevice.orientationDidChangeNotification)) { _ in
                guard let scene = UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.windowScene else { return }
                self.isPortrait = scene.interfaceOrientation.isPortrait
            }
        } detail: {
            Text("Select a department: \(self.isPortrait ? "yes" : "no")")
        }
    }
}
```

For reference, this is what the Home app looks like in different layouts. Note the forced and optional sidebar in each layout. I want to accomplish the same.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: How do you want it to behave when split screen is used? If you want it to depend on the proportions of the width and height then you could just use a `GeometryReader` at the top level to measure the actual view size.

Comment: When horizontalSizeClass == .compact the SidebarMainView is replaced with a TabView instead

Comment: @BenzyNeez I added some images to further showcase what I want

Comment: I don't really understand what the problem is. The environment variable `horizontalSizeClass` can be examined at first launch. If you want to know if the height is greater than the width then use a `GeometryReader`. There is no need to inspect the device orientation at all (and it is better not to, because it does not change when split screen is used). It would also be better to avoid deprecated symbols (`windows` is deprecated).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**For iOS 17+**
We can use `UIDevice.orientationDidChangeNotification` to detect current orientation and `toolbar(removing:)` for removing sidebar toggle button.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var deviceOrientation = UIDevice.current.orientation

    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView {
            Text("sidebar")
                .detectOrientation($deviceOrientation)
                // After removing sidebar toggle, it was not adding when refreshing (Instead Visibility solves the problem)
                // .toolbar(removing:  isOrientationPortrait() ? .none : .sidebarToggle)
                .toolbar(isOrientationPortrait() ? .visible : .hidden, for: .navigationBar)
        } detail: {
            Text("Detail")
        }
    }

    private func isOrientationPortrait() -> Bool {
        return deviceOrientation == .portrait || deviceOrientation == .portraitUpsideDown
    }
}


extension View {
    func detectOrientation(_ orientation: Binding<UIDeviceOrientation>) -> some View {
        modifier(DetectOrientation(orientation: orientation))
    }
}

struct DetectOrientation: ViewModifier {
    
    @Binding var orientation: UIDeviceOrientation
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content.onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIDevice.orientationDidChangeNotification)) { _ in
                orientation = UIDevice.current.orientation
            }
    }
}
```

*Hope It Helps !*

Comment: How is isPortrait set here? Note that the solution in the question for IsPortrait doesn't work correctly since it is currently hardcoded to true on first launch and is therefore incorrect when the app launches in landscape mode.

Comment: @OskarPersson I've edited the answer, please look into it.

Comment: @OskarPersson, Kindly upvote it and approve it of bounty if found useful, it helps alot.

Comment: If the iPad is started in portrait mode, then the sidebar cannot be opened because the toggle button is not yet visible.

Comment: @OskarPersson, I've edited the answer, using `visibility` instead of `removing` property of `toolBar` solves the problem, removing method removes the toggle but not automatically adds it when required which was causing the issue....please look into it.

Comment: @OskarPersson, If you are implementing multiple items in `SideView navigationBar` then you have to build custom sidebar button as this method hides whole navigationBar, still you can use the `DetailView navigationBar`

Answer (score 1):

As I wrote in a comment, the basic logic for this layout is quite easy to implement:

- The environment variable `horizontalSizeClass` can be examined at first launch. This tells you if the horizontal size is `regular` or `compact`. However, it doesn't tell you anything about the device orientation.
- To determine whether the height is greater than the width, a `GeometryReader` can be used. This also works at launch and it reports the dimensions of split screen reliably.

However, I found that getting it to work as you described was not quite so straightforward as expected, for three reasons:

1. You said you wanted to switch to a `TabView` for `compact` layout. This does not come for free with `NavigationSplitView`.

-> This requires separate implementation.

2. I found that if launched in landscape orientation, the sidebar toggle would be removed and would never re-appear, even when switching to portrait orientation.

-> To resolve this, an elaborate if-else switch can be used to force the split view to be rebuilt when switching between portrait and landscape.

3. When two-thirds split mode is used in landscape orientation, the height may be smaller than the width on some devices (especially if safe-area insets are not ignored). Technically, this is landscape orientation, but you showed in your screenshot that you want the sidebar toggle to be visible.

-> To resolve this, the height:width ratio can be compared to a threshold of, say, 0.9.

So here's my attempt to get it working. Hope it helps:

```swift
enum NavDestination: Int, CaseIterable, Identifiable {
    case one = 1
    case two = 2
    case three = 3

    var id: Int {
        self.rawValue
    }

    var title: String {
        "\(self)".capitalized
    }

    var iconName: String {
        "\(self.rawValue).circle"
    }
}

struct SidebarMainView: View {
    @State private var selection: NavDestination? = .one
    @Environment(\.horizontalSizeClass) private var horizontalSizeClass
    let minHeightWidthRatioPortrait = 0.9

    private func detailView(for navDestination: NavDestination) -> some View {
        Text(navDestination.title)
            .font(.largeTitle)
    }

    private var tabView: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selection) {
            ForEach(NavDestination.allCases) { dest in
                detailView(for: dest)
                    .tabItem {
                        Label(dest.title, systemImage: dest.iconName)
                    }
                    .tag(dest)
            }
        }
    }

    private func splitView(isPortrait: Bool) -> some View {
        NavigationSplitView {
            List(NavDestination.allCases, selection: $selection) { dest in
                Label(dest.title, systemImage: dest.iconName)
                    .tag(dest)
            }
            .listStyle(.sidebar)
            .toolbar(removing: isPortrait ? .none : .sidebarToggle)
            .navigationTitle("HP")
        } detail: {
            if let selection {
                detailView(for: selection)
            } else {
                Text("Please select an option")
            }
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        if horizontalSizeClass == .compact {
            tabView
        } else {
            GeometryReader { proxy in
                let w = proxy.size.width
                let h = proxy.size.height
                let heightWidthRatio = h / max(1, w)
                let isPortrait = heightWidthRatio >= minHeightWidthRatioPortrait

                // An elaborate if-else is necessary in order to force
                // the sidebar toggle to be shown when changing to
                // portrait orientation, for the case of when the
                // view is initially launched in landscape orientation
                // (with sidebar hidden). Using a single function call
                // and passing the flag as parameter is not sufficient
                if isPortrait {
                    splitView(isPortrait: true)
                } else {
                    splitView(isPortrait: false)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The screenshots are from an iPad mini.

[image: Screenshots]

Answer (score -2):

**if** `windowWidth < WindowHieght` **then** `use navigation Tab Bar` **else** `use side menu navigation`

it is a s simple as that

Comment: See the first two images in the question. Both use a sidebar but the first one is forced open and the second one is toggleable. It is only in split view, when height > width, I want to use a tab bar instead.